# Поясните, пожалуйста, почему отсутствует запятая?

Tags: запятые, тире, бсп

Почему отсутствует запятая, которая должна была бы закрыть придаточную часть?

***Пишут, чтобы мы обязательно приезжали — будут встречать.***

Answer (score 1):

Вот как это предложение выглядит **в правилах Розенталя:**  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

7. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если она (нередко — неполное предложение) имеет изъяснительное значение (перед ней можно вставить союз что), причем в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта:  ***Пишут, чтобы мы обязательно приезжали — будут встречать.***

Почему отсутствует запятая, которая должна была бы закрыть придаточную часть? Каждый школьник знает, что постановка знаков препинания преимущественно независимая и придаточное предложение следует закрывать, то есть ставить запятую.

**Может быть, ошибся Розенталь?** Но все учебные сайты, включая Грамоту.ру, перепечатывают этот материал и ничего не исправляют. **Значит, всё правильно?** И на нашем форуме никто не отвечает на этот вопрос.

**Ладно, скажу вам по секрету** (хотя, признаться, меня здесь мало кто слушает или даже вообще читает).

Обратите внимание на следующее замечание: **"...причем в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта".**

**А как выглядит это интонационное предупреждение, кто-нибудь знает?** Это и есть главный секрет. Интонационное предупреждение — это интонация, соответствующая постановке **двоеточия**, а именно: **неполное понижение голоса перед увеличенной паузой** (так определяется этот вид интонации у Кустовой).

А здесь нет понижения голоса, фактически это разделительная интонация: голос перед паузой повышается, **выражая взаимообусловленность** двух  предложений: ***приезжайте — будем встречать.***

Попробуем закрыть придаточное предложение запятой: ***Пишут, чтобы мы обязательно приезжали, — будут встречать.***

В таком варианте реализована **присоединительная** интонация с понижением голоса (**как при двоеточии!**), и последнее предложение относится ко всему СПП.

Таким образом, "интонационное предупреждение" присутствует, а взаимообусловленность второго и третьего предложений не выражена.

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь говорит, что тире здесь ставится вместо слова "что". Получается, что имеем два придаточных:
*Пишут, чтобы мы обязательно приезжали, что будут встречать.* || Тире с запятой между придаточными не ставится — в этом нет смысла и вообще нет таких примеров.

Здесь нет противопоставления. Слово "это" тоже не подходит после тире. Тире по смыслу можно заменить на союз "и" (то есть характер интонации перечислительный), перед которым тире с запятой не ставится.

Для противопоставления нужно, чтобы после тире по смыслу подходил союз "а". Для этого нужно переделать предложение:
*Не просто пишут, чтобы мы обязательно приезжали, — (а) даже будут встречать.*
Здесь уже нет перечислительной интонации, части не абсолютно самостоятельны, а одна продолжает из другую.
Вообще, тире с запятой используется тогда, когда части тесно связаны по смыслу, а не всегда, когда есть придаточное.