# Зачем нужно отличать единый знак от сочетания знаков (запятая и тире)? На практике!

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение, знак, единый

1. В **[ПАС под ред. Лопатина §132](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/#id-11%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%C2%A7132)**   есть примечание:

Употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания **следует отличать** от сочетания запятой и тире, когда каждый знак стоит **на собственном основании:**

*Кто знает, **сколько придется пробыть в тайге,** – и все время будет за спиной Гринька и его товарищи* (Шукш.) Запятая закрывает придаточную часть предложения, а тире разделяет части сложносочиненного предложения.

2. А почему **следует отличать?** **Графика** одинаковая, **произношение,** как я думаю, тоже.

**Грамматика?** Три предикативные основы, поэтому можно на границе блоков поставить **единый знак**.

3. Это не только **философия, но и практика тоже.** Так, вопрос о закрытии **запятой** придаточных предложений возникает часто, например **[в этой теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456619/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F), [а также в этой](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454226/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%A1%D0%9F).**

В то же время при решении задач **методом блоков** проблем бы не было. При выборе знака учитывается вид **смысловых** отношений (тире или единый знак), а не **сочетание** знаков (запятая + тире), которое не всегда можно определить **однозначно.**